# Can pointwise quotients be lifted to a local quotient for a family of vector bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve. Let $E_T$ be a family of vector bundles parameterised by scheme $T$ i.e a vector bundle over $X \times T$. Let for each $t \in T$ we have a surjection from $O_{X \times t}^p \to E_{X \times t}$.

> Given a $t$ can I find an open set $V \subset T$ such that we have a surjection $O_{X \times V}^p \to E_{X \times V}$?

The situation is that we have quotient maps for each $t$, if I can at all produce a map (not necessarily surjection) on a neighborhood then I can proceed to show surjection (doing some stalk argument). But I am unable to glue the pointwise quotients to produce a local quotient on an open nbd.

Comment: Could you add a bit more context where the maps $\mathcal O^p_{X \times t} \to E_{X \times t}$ come from? Intuitively they should vary continuously, otherwise you have no chance to glue them together.